# Windows8.1からoneDriveを削除したいのですが、削除方法を教えて下さい。

Tags: windows-8.1

oneDriveをインストールして使用していましたが、社用PCの為、パスワード設定を辞めるよう言われました。
oneDriveのパスワード設定解除するより、削除したいので方法を教えて下さい。
方法が無ければ、パスワードの解除方法でも構いません。
宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2):

onedriveはWindows8.1と統合されているために削除できませんが、8.1pro以上であれば無効化することが可能です。
[Windows 8.1 Tips 集﻿ - OneDrive を無効にする - マイクロソフト コミュニティ](http://answers.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/wiki/windows8_1-files/windows-81-tips-%E9%9B%86-onedrive/5cfd66f5-c09d-4165-8e13-d6b9ad7edc90)

この場合の手順は上記のリンク先に書かれているとおりで、グループポリシーエディタ（gpedit.msc）を使用して設定を修正する形になります。社用PCということであればもしかしたらグループポリシー設定は制限されているかもしれません。その場合はドメイン管理者への相談が必要となります。

他の解説はこちらにありますが英文です。8.1以外のケースについても触れられています。
[How to Completely Disable OneDrive - Microsoft Community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/wiki/odoptions-oddesktop/how-to-completely-disable-onedrive/b97a8336-62e7-476c-872c-3286c0a01cf6)

この解説では無効化ではなく同期させない手順が示されています。要するにWindows8.1にログインするアカウントとマイクロソフトアカウントとの紐付けを解除する形になります。
8.1Homeだとおそらくこちらのパターンしかないでしょう。